# keyboard hook interact with all desktops c++ win32

Tags: c++, keyboard, desktop, hook

Is it possible to make a keyboard hook work on all desktops? For example, could I make it record keys on the winlogon desktop and interactive desktop at the same time? If so how? Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Figured it out. I modified ctrl2cap driver to log keys.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [GINA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380543(VS.85).aspx) (or any other Trojan key loggers)

Comment: FYI, GINA dlls are deprecated starting with Vista.